# How to set a custom spinner?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I wanted to change the text-color of the items in my spinner so I created custom_spinner.xml, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/spinner_item_linear_layout" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView        
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="@color/White"
  android:background="@color/Blue"
  android:id="@+id/spinner_textView" >        
</TextView>



 </LinearLayout>
```

I think this is OK. But the problem is that whenI want to give this custom spinner to the ArrayAdapter, Eclipse throws "my_spinner cannot be resolved or is not a field" exception. My code for it is following:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.my_spinner, projectList);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `android.R` means `R` is in the android package. your R is not in the android package.

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.my_spinner, projectList);
```

R should be your R.java // check your import

Check this example for custom spinner -

http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107

Comment: Thank you, eclipse doesn't throw the exception now. But when I launch my app with this ArrayAdapter it crashes. But when I launch it with the system spinner (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) it works. Do you now what's the problem? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You have to use custom adaper to use custom spinner layout. Check this link ..  http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107